# How can I get values of array out of object in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iteration

I'm building a version of battleship where the ships are worms and the player is the bird...if that explains the naming of things.

I'm having a moment.  I need to iterate through the values of a nested array of coordinates but I simply cannot figure it out.

Here is what array looks like:

```
[{"grub": [23, 24]}, {"earthworm": [34, 35, 36]}, {"larvae": [77, 78, 79]}]
```

I need to iterate through all the nested objects, and then iterate through the array inside that nested object to see if the input matches values.

Function input will be a coordinate with 2 digits (example  '84')

Output should be a boolean stating if the coordinate exists in any of the arrays that are a value of the object.

I have lots of ideas, but none have been successful.

Comment: Please show the ideas you've attempted and how they came up short.

Comment: that data structure looks weird, why can't you use one single object?

Comment: In general, an array of objects with different keys in each object is a poor idea. Either use a single object, or an array of objects with consistent keys, e.g. `{name: "grub", coordinates: [23, 24]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [{"grub": [23, 24]}, {"earthworm": [34, 35, 36]}, {"larvae": [77, 78, 79]}];

const f=(n,data)=>data.map(Object.values).some(([i])=>i.includes(n));

console.log(f(35, data));
console.log(f(84, data));
```

Comment: Simple, I don't understand why it works yet but I'm going to read documentation so I never have to ask this question again :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Array.prototype.some`

```js
const array = [{"grub": [23, 24]}, {"earthworm": [34, 35, 36]}, {"larvae": [77, 78, 79]}]

handleInput()

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', ({ target: { value } }) => handleInput(value))

function handleInput(value) {
  const isItem = isValueInNestedArray(+value, array)
  document.querySelector('p').textContent = isItem ? 'yes' : 'no'
}

function isValueInNestedArray(value, array) {
  return array.some(item => Object.values(item).some(arr => arr.some(coord => coord === value)))
}
```

```html
<input>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Thank you much, I love how you provided detail on how to implement the solution.  Very much appreciated.